# extracting nested struct data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, mgo

Have a struct as follows

```
type Person struct {
   ID    bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
   Name  string        `json:"name"`
   Phone string        `json:"phone"`
}
```

and then want to nest it in another struct

```
type Customer struct {
   ID        bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
   StoreName string
   Person    Person        `json:"persons"`
}
```

instantiated as

```
customer := Customer{bson.NewObjectId(), "Seattle", p1}
```

and insterted into Mongo db (I am using the mgo driver for golang)

```
err = databaseConnection.Insert(&customer)
```

How do I retrieve the customer struct from the DB using parameters from the nested Person struct? E.g. pull all Customer structs that have a Person struct named “John”

I am trying

```
err = databaseConnection.Find(bson.M{XXXXXXXXX}).All(&resultsB)
```

but I can’t figure out what XXXXXX should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like that: `bson.M{"person.name": "john"}`

check mongodb documentation on embedded documents: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/

Comment: I added the bson notation in the struct 
type Customer struct {
   ID        bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
   StoreName string
   Person    Person        `bson:"persons",json:"persons"`
}

and then used it in the query (note the persons with an ‘s’)
err = dbc.Find(bson.M{"persons.name": "GNXGJKMOFM"}).One(&resultsB)

This worked

Comment: Also I think you can remove the ID field from Person, usually you have one ID per object and the nested objects don't have  IDs.